# How much security would I lose if I enabled "easy enter" pins on an android device?

Tags: authentication, android

There is an option on android devices to unlock when the correct pin/password is entered, but without the user explicitly pressing the "done" or "enter" button. How much security does this remove from the device? is there any sort of limit to prevent many login attempts via this method? (granted, one may not know if this option is enabled or not... )

Are there other systems besides android that have this feature? what sort of mitigation do they implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not take away any security. Simple, Easy enter pins would simply auto-OK or auto-ENTER when 4 digits have been entered - just like iPhone. However, it would still mean that incorrect attempts are counted and at too many attempts the device is locked and require online authentication via google account.

The implications "Easy Enter" could have, is if the device is in pocket along with some other things in your pocket, and it accidentially push the home or Power button leading the touchscreen being activated, then Those things (like keys, wallets etc) can accidentially enter too many incorrect pins in a row , causing the device to be locked.

Comment: Does that mean that it will allow a person to guess how long the pin/password is by going up to X and then checking if it counted as an attempt or not? (not that knowing the length in of itself is a great vulnerability, but it can alert a person to a weak length).

Comment: Yes. However, its common that PINs are 4 digit thus it will not reveal anything more than the attacker already knows.